# How to change the default HTML to lang="fr" in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, french

When I use "!" + tabs, the default HTML is set to lang="en".

How can I configure VS Code so that the default language coding is set to lang="fr" ?

I would like that the default VS Code to be always set in French, but I don't want to have VS Code interface in French. Just for all the coding aspect.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Open settings:

[image]

2. Search for `emmet`:

[image]

3. Scroll down to `variables` section and add new variable by clicking `Add item`:

[image]